# Add class and insert before div

Tags: jquery, insert, addclass

I would like to be able to add the class `"wp"` to each anchor tag that is before my `"sub-menu dropdown-menu"` class. How do I do this?

**My Current HTML:**

```
  <a href="google.com">one</a>

  <ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
   <li id="menu-item-5">
    <a href="">five</a>
  </li>
  </ul>

  <a href="google.com">one</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-5">
      <a href="">five</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**Desired Output**

```
 <a href="google.com" class="wp">one</a>

 <a href="google.com" class="wp">one</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `.prev` method for that.

`.prev('a')` finds the previous immediate sibling of the selector only if it finds it.

```
$('.sub-menu.dropdown-menu').prev('a').addClass('wp');
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DTeq/12/)**

To make it work better you can try this as well

```
$('.sub-menu.dropdown-menu').prevAll('a').first().addClass('wp');
```