# Add class that is above it, example add class "act" to the "<ul>" above the "li.item1"

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert

can you help me please? similar to this one [Add class and insert before div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202064/add-class-and-insert-before-div), but I'd like to be able to add the class **"act"** to a class above, equal to below:

> How are:

```
  <ul>
   <li id="item1"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li id="item2"></li>
  </ul>
```

> How do i need:

```
  <ul class="act">
   <li id="item1"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li id="item2"></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#item1').parentElement.classList.add('act');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add `act` class for parent of `#item1`. use like this

> (@Jay Marvin submitted already)

```
$('#item1').parent('ul').addClass('act');
```

If you want to add `act` class for all parent `ul`, use like below

```
$('li').parent('ul').addClass('act');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, I needed all that were "#item1" assigned the "act" and the other codes were not working, this worked perfectly thank you ...

Answer (score 2):

You should first get the `<li>` element as it has an id and would be easy to select

```
 const item = document.getElementById('item1')
 // Or if you use jquery
 const item = $('#item1')
```

That you can get the parent element which is `<ul>` and add the class

```
 const parent = item.parentElement;
 parent.classList.add('act');
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery you could do it like this.

$('#item1').parent().addClass('act');

For more reference please check this link: https://api.jquery.com/parent/